# Android storing GPS in jpeg gets corrupted

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, exif, android-gps

I have created a simple Android-Application that takes a photo and stores the devices GPS infos in the exif-tags for the jpg-file. The following code shows this process (i know it's messy)

```
Android.Locations.Location loc = await client.GetLastLocationAsync();
ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
buffer.Get(bytes);

using (var output = new FileOutputStream(mFile))
{
    try
    {
        output.Write(bytes);
        output.Flush();

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mFile.AbsolutePath);
        string[] degMinSec = Location.Convert(loc.Latitude, Format.Seconds).Split(':');
        string dms = degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1" + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";

        string[] degMinSec1 = Location.Convert(loc.Longitude, Format.Seconds).Split(':');
        string dms1 = degMinSec1[0] + "/1," + degMinSec1[1] + "/1" + degMinSec1[2] + "/1000";

        exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLatitude, dms);
        exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLatitudeRef, loc.Latitude < 0?"S":"N");
        exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLongitude, dms1);
        exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLongitudeRef, loc.Longitude < 0 ? "W" : "E");
        exif.SaveAttributes();

    }
    ...
```

So now to the **problem**:
When i take a picture and debug the *loc* variable, it looks as this:
[image]

as you can see, the latitude is 48.4080605 and de longitude is 15.6257273

when i debug the converted values **dms** & **dms1** they show these values:[image]

dms represents latitude and has the value 48° 24' 29.0178'', dms1 represents longitude and has the value 15° 37' 32.61828''.

when i look at the pictures exif-data in metapicz.com it shows these values:

[image]

can anyone explain me what is going on and what i'm doing wrong?
i can't figure out why it shows a different location than it should

Comment: `when i look at the pictures exif-data in metapicz.com` Wrong. You should read those exif values yourself directly after you put them in. And compare.

Comment: when i look at them in the windows explorer and convert them [with this tool](https://www.latlong.net/degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-degrees) to decimal they represent the same location as when i look at them with metapicz.com

Comment: `You should read those exif values yourself directly after you put them in. Or later as you wish. And compare.`

Comment: `string dms = degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1" + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";` Should that not be `string dms = degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1," + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";` ?

Comment: DId you try with that extra comma i added?

Comment: yes indeed, and i think another problem is that the format.seconds() method returns a comma (,) in the seconds-field and no period (.)

Comment: Whats easier then to replace a comma by a dot?

Comment: nothing, but same as with the missing comma, i just didn't see and realise the error

Comment: Well.... does all go ok when you apply the changes?

Comment: yes, the problems are fixed. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dms = degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1" + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";
```

Should that not be

```
dms = degMinSec[0] + "/1," + degMinSec[1] + "/1," + degMinSec[2] + "/1000";
```

?